# Can I combo Dismiss Into Dream with Living Inferno or Cauldron of Souls?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, at the Prerelease this past weekend I pulled a [Dismiss Into Dream](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dismiss%20Into%20Dream) from the packs I won.

I LOVE the flavor of this card and I think I could abuse it. I wanted to check on rulings though:

1. Dismiss Into Dream + [Living Inferno](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Living%20Inferno): Would I be able to declare the targets and then they would all have to be sacrificed before they dealt damage to Living Inferno? And furthermore, could I choose any number and just have them all take 0 damage?
2. Dismiss Into Dream + [Cauldron of Souls](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cauldron%20of%20Souls): Same sort of question: Could I target them then they have to be sacrificed before the creatures get Persist?

Comment: A lot of 7 drops can be "abused" - I think the idea is if you can play a 7 drop in a constructed format, it really should win you the game.

Comment: @corsiKa I almost exclusively play casual and limited. And the casual I play is very, very slow multiplayer (most often) which means we get to set up grand strategies and execute them. It's a pretty good time and this card fits perfectly into what I play.

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen Here's a [gatherer search](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=1&text=+%5B%22any%20number%20of%20target%20creatures%22%5D) with more "any number of target creature" options. [Sway of Illusion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=22999) in particular seems to fit perfectly mechanically and thematically. A board wipe when Dismiss into Dream is in play, *and* draw a card, all for the low cost of two mana! [Artful Dodge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262840) also seems an exceptional fit.

Comment: @ghoppe Thanks! I did see those and I added them to my deck list. I am getting pretty excited for this deck with the release of M14.

Comment: Just remember to target one of your own creatures with Sway of illusion so that it still resolves and you get your card! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is powerful, but for 7 that is to be expected.

Targeting a creature affected by Dismiss Into Dream will have them sacrificed before the spell/ability targeting them resolves. This is because the effect created by Dismiss Into Dream will go on the stack after the spell targeting the creature.

To address your specific questions:

No on your combo with living inferno, a ruling on gatherer prevents you from assigning 0 damage:

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=96874

> You divide the damage among the target creatures as you activate Living Inferno's ability. Each target must be assigned at least 1 damage.

Yes, on your combo with Cauldron of souls.

Comment: Oooo this makes me happy. I also am looking at Sea King's Blessing for a U board wipe.. This is extra good since I play multiplayer often, this sort of thing tends to pay off quite well. Thanks for the answer! As a side note, I did read your first paragraph, with the stack. So wouldn't Living Inferno get dealt a ton of damage after all the creatures are sacrificed? Or does his ability look for the creatures at the time of resolution?

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen good question... I do not know the answer. The damage dealt to living inferno is determined at resolution time while the creatures are in the graveyard.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I would have to look into. Also, it applies for the Cauldron: The cards would be in the graveyard when they gained persist in which case, they probably wouldn't return at all, since they didn't die with persist.

Comment: For the cauldron, they would not come back. The wording on persist says something like 'when a card with persist goes to the graveyard and does not have a -1/-1 counter' IIRC. They would be in the graveyard before having persist.

Comment: Got it. Cool. Do you know where I could look up something like the ruling on Living Inferno? Or at this point would I have to just find someone who knows the rulings on that?

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen Ask it on this site as a new question. There are lots of people on this site that will know the answer.

Comment: Done. http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/if-creatures-targeted-by-living-infernos-ability-all-die-what-happens

Comment: Living Inferno's ability fizzles.  It never takes damage