# If creatures targeted by Living Inferno's ability all die, what happens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I were to target a ton of creatures with [Living Inferno](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=96874)'s ability and then all those creatures were to die (or be sacrificed, per [Dismiss Into Dream](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370796)) in response to Living Inferno's ability going on the stack, what would happen?

I can see one of two things:

1. The creatures die, then LI's ability checks for the creatures, sees that they aren't there, and then fizzles.
2. When LI's ability goes on the stack it records the creatures power, thus ensuring that LI gets dealt damage when it's ability resolves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The ability fizzles **if and only if**,  **all** of it's targets are gone, so long at least one of it's targets is still there, It will still resolve and deal damage to that target, but if they're all gone, the ability is countered(fizzles)
- Creatures on the battle field can't perform actions(such as dealing damage) if they are illegal targets of the ability, and they're illegal targets of the ability if they've changed zones(such as from the battlefield to the graveyard).
  If they died while [living Inferno](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=living%20Inferno)'s ability was on the stack, than those creates would not deal damage.

both of these points are covered by section 608.2b of the comp rules

> 608.2b
> If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are
> still legal. **A target that’s no longer in the zone it
> was in when it was targeted is illegal.** Other changes to the game
> state may cause a target to no longer be legal; for example, its
> characteristics may have changed or an effect may have changed the
> text of the spell. If the source of an ability has left the zone it
> was in, its last known information is used during this process. **The
> spell or ability is countered if all its targets, for every instance
> of the word “target,” are now illegal.** If the spell or ability is not
> countered, it will resolve normally. **However, if any of its targets
> are illegal, the part of the spell or ability’s effect for which it is
> an illegal target can’t perform any actions on that target, make
> another object or player perform any actions on that target, *or make
> that target perform any actions.*** The effect may still determine
> information about illegal targets, though, and other parts of the
> effect for which those targets are not illegal may still affect them.

> Example:
> Sorin’s Thirst is a black instant that reads, “Sorin’s Thirst
> deals 2 damage to target creature and you gain 2 life.” If the
> creature isn’t a legal target during the resolution of Sorin’s Thirst
> (say, if the creature has gained protection from black or left the
> battlefield), then Sorin’s Thirst is countered. Its controller doesn’t
> gain any life.

> Example:
> Plague Spores reads, “Destroy target nonblack
> creature and target land. They can’t be regenerated.” Suppose the same
> animated land is chosen both as the nonblack creature and as the land,
> and the color of the creature land is changed to black before Plague
> Spores resolves. Plagues Spores isn’t countered because the black
> creature land is still a legal target for the “target land” part of
> the spell. The “destroy target nonblack creature” part of the spell
> won’t affect that permanent, but the “destroy target land” part of the
> spell will still destroy it. It can’t be regenerated.

This is also supported by the [Gatherer ruling for pit fight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366450)

> 1/24/2013     If either target of Pit Fight is an illegal target when the
> ability tries to resolve, neither creature will deal or be dealt
> damage.

take note that [pit fight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=pit%20fight) does not fizzle in this case, because it still will have 1 target.

---

if [pit fight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=pit%20fight) isn't good enough for you because it uses the `fight` mechanic, than the ruling for [Flesh/Blood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368991&part=Blood) also applies

> 4/15/2013     As Blood is resolving, if only one of the targets is legal,
> Blood will still resolve but will have no effect: If the first target
> is illegal, it can’t deal damage to anything. If the second target
> creature or player is illegal, it can’t be dealt damage.

Comment: Thanks! So, hypothetically if one of the creatures survived, I assume the ability would only affect the one creature and then only that one creature would deal damage to Living Inferno?

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen yup

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen, actually if one creature survives, the Last Known Information (LKI) of the dead creatures are used to deal damage to Living Inferno (along with the surviving creature)

Comment: @user1873 are you sure about that? I would interpret the quoted text to mean that that part of the ability can't "make that target perform any actions".

Comment: @tengfred, the non-bolded part agrees with [CR608.2g], "The effect may still determine information about illegal targets, though, and other parts of the effect for which those targets are not illegal may still affect them." Living Inferno needs to know information about **all the creatures** it targeted, even the ones that are now illegal because they no longer exist (in the graveyard, in a players hand because they were bounced, etc.) in the zone where it expected them, so LKI is used for those creatures to, "deal damage equal to their power" to Living Inferno.

Comment: @user1873 I'll admit to not being a magic rules expert, but it still seems strange to me. Maybe action has some special technical meaning here, but otherwise, I'd expect dealing damage to be an action. If it had been e.g. "then you gain life equal to the total power of those creatures", it would make more sense to me to use LKI.(Although I still would probably have got it wrong before this discussion :))

Comment: @user1873 Damage is calculated on resolution. As per the gathering ruling: "The amount of damage Living Inferno will deal is locked in as you activate its ability, since you're dividing damage. If Living Inferno's power changes after its ability is activated but before it resolves (via Giant Growth, for example), the amount of damage Living Inferno deals won't change. The same is *not* true for the amount of damage dealt to Living Inferno by the other creatures, which is determined when the ability resolves."

Comment: @ghoppe that's really not a relevant ruling.  The reason why Living Inferno doesn't take damage is not directly about whether or not the targets have changed zones.  It's because they have become illegal targets.

Comment: @SamIam of course you're right, as I have realized. :)

Comment: @ghoppe actually, that ruling would be somewhat relevant if posted on user1873's answer because it illustrates the difference between the language in rule 112.7a and the damage being dealt to LI

Comment: @ikegami I had a little doubt myself until I read the Gather ruling for [Pit Fight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366450)

Comment: @Sam I am, That's because *fight* explicitly checks if both creatures to exist.

Comment: @SamIam, you cannot use **Fight** as an example, because the rules specifically tell you not to assign damage if either Target ceases to exist, " 701.10b If a creature instructed to fight is no longer on the battlefield or is no longer a creature, no damage is dealt. If a creature is an illegal target for a resolving spell or ability that instructs it to fight, no damage is dealt." If **Fight** didn't explicitly tell you that, then CR112.7a and CR608.2g would instruct you to use LKI.

Comment: @user1873 What about the last part of CR608.2b? It cannot be ignored. *"However, if any of its targets are illegal, the part of the spell or ability’s effect for which it is an illegal target can’t perform any actions on that target, make another object or player perform any actions on that target, or make that target perform any actions."* Clearly, Living Inferno cannot force an illegal target to deal damage. I believe the explicit rules you mention for the keyword **fight** are a direct consequence of CR608.2b, and not just grafted onto the rules.

Comment: Thought experiment: What if Living Inferno were instead a Psionic Inferno (see [Psionic Entity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=2178)) "{T}: Psionic Inferno deals damage equal to its power divided as you choose among any number of target creatures and X damage to itself where X is the total power of the targeted creatures." — *then* 112.7a kicks in.

Comment: @ikegami you have a similar ruling for `flesh/blood`

Comment: @Sam I am, I stand corrected

Comment: ...I missed that it was covered by the rule you quoted.

Comment: I've actually become uncertain on this one again, I'll probably edit it